# How to delete all Commits by author on GitHub Local and Remote branch?

Tags: git, github, git-bash

One of the user wrongly updated commits for last 3 months (don't have the exact date). Want to delete all his commits by the author name in single branch .

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "Roman" ];
then
        skip_commit "$@";
else
        git commit-tree "$@";
fi' HEAD
```

It's not working, please also share the way to make the changes on remote as well.

```
Branch name : development
Author name : Roman
Commits : 750
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you know that is not working? Do you just want to remove the commits, or do you want to back out the changes made in the commits as well? The filter-branch command that you show does not remove the changes, only the commits.

Comment: want to delete the changes by author made in all his commits.

Comment: no one can see his commits online.

Comment: Then filter-branch is the wrong tool. Think about doing a big rebase.

Comment: as i haven't used it before

Comment: delete the changes and commits as well